# MVC Paging: Post method instead of Get method

Tags: post, razor, model-view-controller, pagedlist

When i click on the paging link below the table the control goes the GET method and all my data in the grid is lost.

Is there any way to redirect the control to the POST method when i click on the paging numbers.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Html.ActionLink you can do it simple

```
Html.ActionLink(
            "Title", // <--Yuor title
            "Item",   // <-- ActionMethod
            "Login",  // <-- Controller Name.
            null, // <-- Route arguments.
            null  // <-- htmlArguments .. which are none. 
                  //     There you can set HTTP method, which will be requested
            )
```